# Как сверстать семейное древо на css?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

Как можно сверстать такое семейное древо на css?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это будет что-то страшное. На одном css )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

И я вставлю свои пять копеек: вариант на SVG

> 100% кроссбраузерно и работает везде и 100% адаптивно

```css
text {
  font-size: 14px;
  fill: #666;
  cursor: pointer;
}

text:hover {
  fill: #000ccc;
}

rect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #ccc;
}

line {
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 660 270" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <rect x="300" y="10" ry="4"/>
    <text x="335" y="27">Отец</text>
    <line x1="350" x2="350" y1="35" y2="50"/>
    <path d="m100,80 v-30 h350 v30"/>
    <rect x="50" y="80" ry="4"/>
    <rect x="400" y="80" ry="4"/>
    <text x="90" y="97">сын</text>
    <text x="435" y="97">дочь</text>
    <line x1="100" x2="100" y1="105" y2="125" />
    <rect x="50" y="125" ry="4"/>
    <text x="75" y="142">правнук</text>
    <line x1="450" x2="450" y1="105" y2="125"/>
    <path d="m200,155 v-30 h400 v30"/>
    <line x1="450" x2="450" y1="125" y2="155"/>
    <rect x="150" y="155" ry="4"/>
    <rect x="400" y="155" ry="4"/>
    <rect x="550" y="155" ry="4"/>
    <text x="180" y="172">внучка</text>
    <text x="437" y="172">внук</text>
    <text x="580" y="172">внучка</text>
    <line x1="450" x2="450" y1="180" y2="210"/>
    <path d="m340,240 v-30 h210 v30"/>
    <line x1="450" x2="450" y1="210" y2="240"/>
    <rect x="290" y="240" ry="4"/>
    <rect x="400" y="240" ry="4"/>
    <rect x="510" y="240" ry="4"/>
    <text x="308" y="257">правнучка</text>
    <text x="425" y="257">правнук</text>
    <text x="528" y="257">правнучка</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

Семейное древо. Решение на CSS.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.tree ul {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 2px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
  background: lightskyblue;
  color: #000;
}

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #999;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.tree li a:hover img,
.tree li a:hover+ul img {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://ss.metronews.ru/userfiles/materials/74/741810/858x540.jpg">Отец</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="https://ss.metronews.ru/userfiles/materials/74/741810/858x540.jpg">Сын</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="https://ss.metronews.ru/userfiles/materials/74/741810/858x540.jpg">Внук</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="https://ss.metronews.ru/userfiles/materials/74/741810/858x540.jpg">Дочь</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="https://ss.metronews.ru/userfiles/materials/74/741810/858x540.jpg">Внучка</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="https://ss.metronews.ru/userfiles/materials/74/741810/858x540.jpg">Внук</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><img src="https://ss.metronews.ru/userfiles/materials/74/741810/858x540.jpg">Правнучка</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><img src="https://ss.metronews.ru/userfiles/materials/74/741810/858x540.jpg">Правнук</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><img src="https://ss.metronews.ru/userfiles/materials/74/741810/858x540.jpg">Правнучка</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="https://ss.metronews.ru/userfiles/materials/74/741810/858x540.jpg">Внучка</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Отличное решение, мне очень понравилось

Comment: ерунда то ерунда ..а вот как это адаптировать ?

Comment: я наверно по этому люблю svg что там это само получается